# ¿Es correcto "la quiero a morir"?

Tags: gramática, expresiones, modismos, letras-de-canciones

Hay una canción con ese título, y en la letra se repite frecuentemente la misma expresión.

¿Es correcta esa expresión? Si lo es, ¿qué significa?

Comment: a morir=en exceso, mucho, con todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Je l'aime **à** mourir" significa o bien que la ama tanto que podría morir debido a que no puede contener tan grande emoción, hacer cualquier cosa que le pidiera o que haría cualquier cosa por su bienestar o bien "hasta que la muerte nos separe" o "Siemore...". Ya que el español no es muy ambiguo se podría decir: "La quiero **hasta** la muerte" o "Moriría **por** ella o La amo **mucho/tanto que no puedo../con locura/a rabiar** según el contexto. Personalmente creo que significa que ella tiene en sus manos su vida porque no la concibe sin su presencia.

En mi español ''**a** morir" es "con todo", "en exceso", "mucho" o más coloquial "hasta las patas". Tambien se usa informalmente como interjección: ¡A morir! Como diciendo que ¡A fondo! ¡A concho! ¡Con todo!

Por el contrario "La quiero **al** morir" lo diría tal vez un personaje cuando está agonizando o alguien narrando su propia muerte.

Answer (score 0):

Expresión "**la quiero a morir**".

---

La canción de Francis Cabrel, "*Je l'aime à mourir*", literalmente "**La amo a morir**", traducida y cantada como "la quiero a morir", es de 1979.

Muchos piensan que esta expresión "**la quiero a morir**" procede o nació de la misma canción y que antes no existía, sin embargo esto no es así, ya que si bien era menos conocida, es bastante más antigua que la canción e incluso se conservan formulas populares  anteriores más complicadas y difíciles de entender hoy en día para la misma locución, aunque bastante menos extendida que la que nos ocupa.

[image]

*Aquí aparece en una obra de Carlos Arniches y Barrera, "**Rositas de olor**" en un sainete madrileño de 1924/1925*.

" *No me pongas a que haga una locura. **Yo te quiero a morir***. "

---

Al menos en el español de España es común leer y escuchar este tipo de expresión junto con otras del mismo estilo o significado, así decimos;

- lo quiero a morir. (a él)
- **la quiero a morir**. (a ella) / (hasta morir / por ella)
- la quiero a rabiar. (a ella)
- lo quiero a rabiar. (a él).
- **la quiero con locura** (a ella).
- lo quiero con locura (a él).

En general la expresión "**la quiero a morir**" significa lo mismo que "querer a alguien con locura", "**la quiero con locura**",  la amo con todo mi corazón **hasta el final**, **hasta la muerte**, con todas mis fuerzas y pasión, con toda mi alma, ... por contra existen otros "**sentimientos opuestos**" y así se puede igualmente decir;

- ... "**la odio a morir**", "lo odio a morir"... "lo odio hasta morir", "la odio hasta morir", "lo odio hasta rabiar", "la odio hasta rabiar"... que viene a ser lo mismo que en el anterior caso, pero en el sentido opuesto.

---

**Otra expresión más antigua**.

---

Como expresión antecedente con el mismo significado "a morir / hasta morir", aparece como "**yo te quiero al morir**" en una obra de Arturo Molinari · 1921 "Libertas, ó La independencia del Perú: drama en cuatro acto, donde uno de sus personajes Angelica dice;

> Sí; más vale que lo sepas de una vez. La goda no se equivoca. **Yo te
> quiero al morir**. Yo te quiero , Puca huma, porque eres hermoso; porque
> eres grande, porque tu alma es noble, como noble son tus actos...

---

[image]

---

*Notas*;

- "*la goda*" se refiere a una mujer española.
- "*al morir*", es una expresión antigua y más difícil de entender hoy en día, "al morir" no significa cuando uno se muere, sino la expresión es conjunta "al morir" (almorir), "Yo te quiero a / hasta "el" morir", "hasta "el" fin", "muchísimo", "hasta dar la vida por ti", "con locura".

En otra expresión parecida pero que no tiene nada que ver con "al morir", salvo la formula de construcción "al o el", es "**al querer**" o "**el querer**", ejemplo, "*me viene "**al querer**" cuando me dices esas palabras*". Es decir, cuando me dices esas palabras me aparecen emociones y sentimientos de cariño, de querer quererte a ti, de amor hacia ti o aquellas otras cosas que se hayan indicado en las palabras. En ese mismo sentido, se dice, "*Esas son las cosas del querer*", es decir, las cosas que se encuentran en el cariño o en el amor.

Por tanto, en ese  "**al querer**". no se trataría de la lógica interna de la actividad a la que tiende "al querer" cuando decimos por ejemplo, "**Al querer comer** *con esos guantes, se le cayó el plato*", no se trata de la acepción de "querer" como tener una voluntad o determinación de hacer algo, sino la acepción de querer a alguien, de tener cariño o inclinación hacia alguien.

Así, en la expresión "**yo te quiero al morir**" "al morir" (almorir), como expresión antecedente, tampoco se trataría de esa lógica interna de la actividad a la que tiende cuando uno o alguien va a morir, "al morir" o hacia la muerte, sino la expresión "al morir" hay que entenderla como "el morir", como un fin en sí mismo. "*yo te quiero hasta el morir*", "*yo te quiero hasta el fin, hasta el final*" "*yo te tendré "querer", "cariño", "amor" hasta la muerte o "el morir"*".

---

A parte de una canción, también es el titulo de una telenovela en Colombia, por lo que entiendo allí la utilización de la expresión "*la quiero a morir*" también debe de ser común.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_quiero_a_morir_(telenovela)

Comment: La Rae en general solo sirve de orientación pues aún posee muchas deficiencias ya que no recoge todo aquello que debería. Te dejo algunos libros donde aparece la expresión. - La última raya de Javier Jorge "... estoy increíblemente enamorado, la quiero a morir, a veces pienso que daría mi vida..." pag. 149.  / - La sombra de la Realidad de Luima "... ahora es el momento de hacer el teatro para que se crea que la quiero a morir, ha perdido la memoria de manera que ..." / - Vidas Unidas de Olvido Macias Valle " La quiero a morir y me quiere a morir, nos peleamos y nos reconciliamos, ..."

Comment: Como expresión antecedente con el mismo significado "a morir / hasta morir", y más complicado de entender hoy en día, aparece como "**yo te quiero al morir**" en una obra de Arturo Molinari de 1921 "Libertas, ó La independencia del Perú: drama en cuatro acto, donde uno de sus personajes dice;

Angélica; Sí; más vale que lo sepas de una vez. La goda no se equivoca. **Yo te quiero al morir**. Yo te quiero , Puca

Comment: La quiero a morir=la quiero a rabiar=la quiero en exceso. Lo dice en forma figurada. En mi país nunca he escuchado "al morir", a menos que lo dijera literalmente y como un recurso poético.

Comment: @cocteau ¿ Y  has oído "al querer" o "el querer"?

Comment: @Diego No entiendo que tiene que ver con la pregunta. "El querer(el acto de estar queriendo)" suena balada o poesía y "Al querer" implica deseo o tenacidad(al querer+acción=cuando estaba tratando de+hacerlo, cuando quise/quiere/quiso/etc+hacerlo)

Comment: al morir(le está pasando eso en ese momento, está muriendo, agonizando)||hasta la muerte(siempre lo va a hacer)||a morir(en exceso, a rabiar, mucho, hasta las patas, con todo)

Comment: @cocteau, no va por ahí la cuestión, no se trata de la lógica interna de la actividad a la que tiende "al querer". Ejem. "Al querer coger la botella con las manos mojadas se le resbalo", no es ese "al querer",  no se trata de la acepción de "querer" como tener una voluntad o determinación de hacer algo, sino la acepción de querer a alguien, de tener cariño o inclinación hacia alguien.  Los términos como "al querer", "el querer", "cosas del querer" son antiguos y expresan aquellos aspectos relacionados con "el querer", "el cariño", "el amor". Y no sabia si en tu país se conoce.

Comment: @cocteau / En ese sentido, "yo te quiero al morir", como expresión antigua y antecedente de "te quiero a morir" es como indico en la respuesta, como decir "yo te quiero hasta el morir", "yo te quiero hasta el fin", "hasta el final", "mucho", "con locura", "tanto que moriría por ti"... Al ser una expresión antigua y en desuso para nosotros, es por tanto más difícil tanto de comprender como de explicar. Como arriba indico, aparece en una obra del Genoves Giovanni Luigi Arturo Molinari Raggio "Libertas, ó La independencia del Perú" en 1921.

Comment: La canción no es de 1921. Estás dándole el mismo sentido a todas las frases, para mi "a el querer" no es equivalente a "al querer" y "a el morir" nadie lo dice, "al morir" es en el momento, "ahora que estoy muriendo" o "en el momento que se murió" y hay matices en las otras y cada una tiene las formas gramaticales de su época. Voy a tratar de adquirir ese libro, pero tratándose de poesía no se puede analizar de la misma forma. Además de que la original está en francés.